# Javascript: Reading node.js HTTP message

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, http-get

I have an HTTP packet with the following information:

```
GET /something?name=joe HTTP/1.1
Host: hostname:8080
Connection: keep-alive
...
```

Using `node.js`, how do I extract the name field?  I have tried looking through the message body and have found it is null, and I am unsure what other options I have or how to get this value.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the related code you have so far? Are you using any particular HTTP server libraries or frameworks? Some will create a `request.query` object which will have the `name` as a property. But, if you're just using Node's own API, you'll have to [`parse`](http://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) the [`request.url`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not always you need to use Express for simple http server solution, you could also the built in modules for this:

The result of requesting: `http://example:8080/user?name=Mike&age=32`

```
var http = require('http'),
    url  = require('url');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    var path = '',
        parsed = url.parse(req.url, true);

    if (parsed.pathname === '/user') {

        // Requested:  { protocol: null,
        //   slashes: null,
        //   auth: null,
        //   host: null,
        //   port: null,
        //   hostname: null,
        //   hash: null,
        //   search: '?name=Mike&age=32',
        //   query: { name: 'Mike', age: '32' },
        //   pathname: '/user',
        //   path: '/user?name=Mike&age=32',
        //   href: '/user?name=Mike&age=32' }
        console.log('Requested: ', parsed);
        path = parsed.pathname;
    }

    res.end('Found path ' + path);
}).listen(8080);
```